# What is the difference between Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite assemblies?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

While encrypting SQLite database using EFCore I came across this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/388)

Refer to comment by bricelam on 1st August. This issue is explaining about how to encrypt the SQLite database using efcore.
It is referring to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core. However there is another package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" which is widely used and referred in many microsoft docs. I would like to know difference between these two assemblies and which one should I use?

Am I going to miss any functionality if I use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core?

Comment: Looking at Github, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite doesn't seem to have much actual code in it, other than pulling in dependencies for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green. I'm not sure what the intention is, but my guess is that you are safe to use either.

Comment: But why does it pull in those other files? Think that's the real value-add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, [EFCore.Sqlite.csproj](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.Sqlite/EFCore.Sqlite.csproj) contains the reference of [EFCore.Sqlite.Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore.Sqlite.Core/EFCore.Sqlite.Core.csproj) and SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green. Entire code base is in **EFCore.Sqlite.Core**. **EFCore.Sqlite.csproj** is just copying SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green and other few files.